# SQL WeekOfYear() stops at end of the year. Alternatives?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have a query that gets executed based on the date range the user chooses. For example: 12-12-2019 to 1-13-2020.

```
// Retrieve count of attendance, no shows and cancellations per user selected category and sort by week number
   $q = "SELECT YEARWEEK(`start_time`, 0) AS weekno,
    SUM(`is_no_show` = 0 AND `is_cancelled` = 0) as attended,
    SUM(`is_no_show` = 1) AS no_shows,
    SUM(`is_cancelled` = 1)AS cancelled
  FROM `myTable`
  WHERE (`start_time` > :start_date  AND `start_time` < :end_date)
  AND category LIKE :cohort_type
  GROUP BY weekno";
```

My issue is that this query stops pulling in data after 12-23-2019. It seems to stop at the last week of the year and not go into 2020 as week 1. How do I account for this? Any suggestions or tips is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

General DB Structure:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| start_time |  no_shows | cancelled | 
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2019-12-20 |     1     |     0     |   
| 2019-12-21 |     0     |     0     |  
| 2019-12-22 |     0     |     1     |
```

GOAL: I want to SUM the data on a weekly basis

EDIT: YEARWEEK() skips the first week of 2020 and goes straight to week 2.

Comment: Is this supposed to be MySQL? Then I doubt that understands the date formats you are giving it in the first place. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Comment: Add YEAR-part to select list and group by

Comment: `':start_date 00:00:00'` and `':end_date 23:59:59'` will not work as you think it should. Any placeholders inside of a quote will be treated as part of the string and not as a placeholder. You'll need to either add the timestamp to the value being bound or use `CONCAT` in mysql. By the way, you can use BETWEEN to make it slightly more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` criteria on the year; as of now, it will mix weeks belonging to different years, which I assume is not what you want. I would suggest using `YEARWEEK()`, which takes the year in account.

Also, your ilter on the date seems akward, as it is mixing parameters and string concatenation; you can use half-open intervals instead (and proper parameter bindings).

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    YEARWEEK(`start_time`) AS weekno,
    SUM(`is_no_show` = 0 AND `is_cancelled` = 0) attended,
    SUM(`is_no_show` = 1) no_shows,
    SUM(`is_cancelled` = 1) cancelled
FROM `attendee_categories_appts_joined`
WHERE 
    `start_time` > :start_date 
    AND `start_time` < :end_date
    AND category LIKE :cohort_type 
GROUP BY weekno
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! It's possible to then convert the YEARWEEK into a date right? For example if I get 202001, then this can be converted to 2020-01-01?

Comment: Actually this skips the first week of the year and goes to the second week of 2020.

Comment: @Miraclefruit: not really. Weeks do span over years, so the first week of the year usually does not start on January first. This is demonstrated in [the MySQL documentation for `YEARWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the YearWeek() output to date in php?